# Acumatica dynamic dropdown

Tags: c#, runtime, dropdown, acumatica

I have a dropdown in a Grid and I want to fill it in runtime. I tried it in a RowSelected event but it doesn't work.

Then I tried it to assign the attribute PXStringList in the field definition on the DAC, but it doesn't work either.

This is the event

```
        protected virtual void HIASetupDetail_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> values = new List<string>();
        values.AddRange(new string[] { "A", "B" });

        if (e.Row == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        HIASetupDetail HIASetupDetailRow = (HIASetupDetail)e.Row;

        PXStringListAttribute.SetList<HIASetupDetail.acumaticaField>(sender, HIASetupDetailRow, values.ToArray(), values.ToArray());
    }
```

And this is the DAC

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public class HIASetupDetail : PX.Data.IBqlTable
{        
    #region AcumaticaField
    public abstract class acumaticaField : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBString()]
    [PXDefault()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Acumatica Field")]
    public virtual string AcumaticaField { get; set; }
    #endregion


}
```

This is the Dropdown in the Grid

Any idea why it doesn't work in the Grid?

Comment: Add `PXStringList` to the DAC, then you should be able to overwrite it's values from code using `PXStringListAttribute.SetList`

Comment: I tried that but it still failing

Comment: Are you getting any errors or it is just not working?

Comment: Just not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example how you can change the Values of the `PXStringListAttribute` while selecting that field:

**The DAC Extension**:

```
public class SOOrderExt:PXCacheExtension<SOOrder>
{

    #region TestField
    [PXString]
    [PXStringList()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Acumatica Field")]
    public string TestField { get; set; }

    public abstract class testField : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
}
```

**The Graph Extension**

```
public class SOOrderEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    public virtual void SOOrder_TestField_FieldSelecting(PXCache sender,PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Row!=null)
        {
            List<string> values = new List<string>();
            values.AddRange(new []{ "First","Second"});
            SOOrder row = (SOOrder)e.Row;
            PXStringListAttribute.SetList<SOOrderExt.testField>(sender, row, values.ToArray(), values.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Also you should be sure that when you added the field to the Page from Layout Editor that it was added as "Combobox"

[image]

As a result you will get the following:

[image]

**UPDATE 1**
For changing the dropdown in the Grid you can use the following code as an example:

**Graph Extension**

```
public class SOOrderEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    public virtual void SOLine_TestField_FieldSelecting(PXCache sender,PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Row!=null)
        {
            List<string> values = new List<string>();
            values.AddRange(new[] { "First", "Second" });
            PXStringListAttribute.SetList<SOLineExt.testField>(sender, null, values.ToArray(), values.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

**DAC Extension**

```
public class SOLineExt : PXCacheExtension<SOLine>
{

    #region TestField
    [PXString]
    [PXStringList()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Acumatica Field")]
    public string TestField { get; set; }

    public abstract class testField : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
}
```

As you can see the difference is in the call of the `PXStringListAttribute.SetList<T>` in case of grid this is working only when passing `null` as row so that the change will be done for all lines.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Samvel! I tried it with this example and it works perfect with a dropdown in the Form, however I tried y with the same example for the dropdown in the Grid and it didn't work for me, let me know if you have any idea why

Comment: Thanks @SamvelPetrosov. It works fine without the if(e.Row!=null)

Comment: Neither Samvel's nor Simon's solutions will work for grids without MatrixMode grid property set to true

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example I did a while ago that displays how to leverage CacheAttached method to dynamicaly populate a string list. It changes the available values depending on the current company.

```cs
public class DynamicDropdownAttribute : PXStringListAttribute
{
    private string[] Values2 = { "A", "C" };
    private string[] Labels2 = { "Alpha", "Charlie" };

    private string[] Values3 = { "N", "C" };
    private string[] Labels3 = { "November", "Charlie" };

    public DynamicDropdownAttribute()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public override void CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
    {
        base.CacheAttached(sender);
        var company = PX.Data.Update.PXInstanceHelper.CurrentCompany;
        if (company == 2)
        {
            this._AllowedValues = Values2;
            this._AllowedLabels = Labels2;
        }
        else if (company == 3)
        {
            this._AllowedValues = Values3;
            this._AllowedLabels = Labels3;
        }
    }
}

public class SOOrderPXExt : PXCacheExtension<SOOrder>
{
    [PXString(1)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Process")]
    [DynamicDropdown]
    public virtual string UsrProcess { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrProcess : IBqlField { }
}
```

The reason you need to use CacheAttached is explained in the T200 certification, available in Acumatica Open University. Here is an excerpt :

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Simon ML, it worked fine. However, I try to load the dropdown values in runtime: I have a local file in the workstation and I want to show several elements in the dropdown. I tried the suggestion of Samvel with the PXStringList on the DAC but it doesn't work

Comment: You have a file you would like to pull the data from ? You can try to load and parse the file during the CacheAttached, it should work.

Comment: Thanks @SimonML! Works fine but I take the Samvel answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem you count comes from the Grid control and not from DAC/Graph.

Because you set different cell formatting for each row, you need to set:

```
<px:PXGrid MatrixMode="True"
```