# Acumatica dynamic dropdown in custom field based on current record status field

Tags: acumatica

I have added a custom field to the BAccount table called UsrSubStatus with a PXStringList of six values.  If the BAccount Status field is "Inactive" (value of I) then the UsrSubStatus dropdown list should only allow selection of 3 of the list values.  If the Status field is other than Inactive then the dropdown list should only allow selection of the other 3 list values.

I found an article: [Acumtica dynamic dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906357/acumatica-dynamic-dropdown/49907964#49907964) that looks very similar to what I am trying to accomplish but it bases the dynamic change based on the current company the user is logged into.

```
 var company = PX.Data.Update.PXInstanceHelper.CurrentCompany;
```

My issue in the following code is how to reference the BAccount Status field in my var status line.

```
 public class DynamicDropdownAttribute : PXStringListAttribute
 {
   #region Event Handlers
   private string[] Values2 = { "A1", "A2", "A3" };
   private string[] Labels2 = { "On-Plan", "Off-Plan", "Services Only" };

   private string[] Values3 = { "I1", "I2", "I3" };
   private string[] Labels3 = { "ROR - Same Product", "ROR - New Product", "Out of Business" };

   public DynamicDropdownAttribute()
       : base()
   {
   }

   public override void CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
   {
       base.CacheAttached(sender);
       var status = sender.CR.Status;
       if (status != "I")
       {
           this._AllowedValues = Values2;
           this._AllowedLabels = Labels2;
       }
       else 
       {
           this._AllowedValues = Values3;
           this._AllowedLabels = Labels3;
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify the source code following this, where `statusField` is your custom field. On the `Customization Project Editor`screen, you should be set the `CommitChanges=true` for the custom field.

```
 public class DynamicDropdown001Attribute : PXStringListAttribute
{
    public const string A1 = "On-Plan";
    public const string A2 = "Off-Plan";
    public const string A3 = "Services Only";

    public DynamicDropdown001Attribute() : base(new string[] { A1,A2,A3 }, new string[] { "On-Plan", "Off-Plan", "Services Only" }) { }
}
public class DynamicDropdown002Attribute : DynamicDropdown001Attribute
{
    public const string I1 = "ROR - Same Product";
    public const string I2 = "ROR - New Product";
    public const string I3 = "Out of Business";
    public DynamicDropdown002Attribute() 
    {
        Array.Resize(ref _AllowedValues, _AllowedValues.Length - 3);
        Array.Resize(ref _AllowedValues, _AllowedValues.Length + 3);
        _AllowedValues[_AllowedValues.Length - 3] = I1;
        _AllowedValues[_AllowedValues.Length - 2] = I2;
        _AllowedValues[_AllowedValues.Length - 1] = I3;
        Array.Resize(ref _AllowedLabels, _AllowedLabels.Length - 3);
        Array.Resize(ref _AllowedLabels, _AllowedLabels.Length + 3);
        _AllowedLabels[_AllowedLabels.Length - 3] = DynamicDropdown002Attribute.I1;
        _AllowedLabels[_AllowedLabels.Length - 2] = DynamicDropdown002Attribute.I2;
        _AllowedLabels[_AllowedLabels.Length - 1] = DynamicDropdown002Attribute.I3;
    }
}
public class DynamicDropdownAttribute : PXStringListAttribute, IPXRowSelectedSubscriber
{
    public Type _StatusField;
    public DynamicDropdownAttribute(Type statusField)
    {
        _StatusField = statusField;
    }
    public void RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        object row = e.Row as object;
        if (row != null)
        {
            bool? filter = (bool?)((string)sender.GetValue(e.Row, _StatusField.Name) == "I");
            PXStringListAttribute.SetList(sender, row, _FieldName, (filter.HasValue && filter.Value ? new DynamicDropdown001Attribute() : new DynamicDropdown002Attribute()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Vardan, In the original article the [DynamicDropdownAttribute] attribute was specified for the custom field.  My UsrSubStatus field is defined in the Data Access section as:

Comment: [PXDBString(25)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Sub-Status")]
[DynamicDropdownAttribute]
I get a validation error stating that the type or namespace DynamicDropdownAttributeAttribute could not be found.

Comment: @JohnWiles Which namespace is using the DynamicDropdownAttribute attribute? `[PXDBString(25,IsUnicode=true)] [PXUIField(DisplayName="Sub-Status")] [DynamicDropdownAttribute(typeof(DACExt.UsrSubStatus))]`

Comment: I changed last line to [DSDSupportEnhancements.DynamicDropdownAttribute(typeof(BAccountExt.usrSubStatus))] and I can publish the project.  But now the dropdown has 4 selection values "On Plan" and the three Inactive options.  When you change the status of the business account the values do not change.

Comment: I also changed the DynamicDropdownAttribute to 1: do a -3 on the length instead of the original 2 and 2: the order of the DynamicDropdown001Attribute() and DynamicDropdown002Attribute() on the last line.  Now I get the three Active dropdown list values in the dropdown.  But it doesn't matter if the business account is Active or Inactive, the list is always the three Active options.

Comment: Did you set your status field to CommitChanges = true ?

Comment: @JohnWiles  I updated the answer source code and description

Answer (score 0):

I really liked the first solution and was able to get some help from Acumatica.  The first step was to define the DAC:

```
[PXDBString(25, IsUnicode=true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Sub-Status", Required = true)]
[PXDefault()]
[PXDependsOnFields(typeof(BAccount.status))]
[PXStringList(
new string[]
{ "A1", "A2", "A3", "I1", "I2", "I3" },
new string[]
{ "On-Plan", "Off-Plan", "Services Only", "ROR - Same Product", "ROR - New Product", "Out of Business" })]
```

Then in the BusinessAccountMaint_Extension graph do the following:

```
private string[] Values2 = { "A1", "A2", "A3" };
private string[] Labels2 = { "On-Plan", "Off-Plan", "Services Only" };
private string[] Values3 = { "I1", "I2", "I3" };
private string[] Labels3 = { "ROR - Same Product", "ROR - New Product", "Out of Business" };

protected void BAccount_Status_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated del)
{
  if(del != null)
    del(cache, e);

  var row = (BAccount)e.Row;
  if(row == null) return;

  BAccountExt rowExt = PXCache<BAccount>.GetExtension<BAccountExt>(row);
  if (row.Status != "I")
      PXStringListAttribute.SetList<BAccountExt.usrSubStatus>(cache, row, Values2, Labels2);
  else
      PXStringListAttribute.SetList<BAccountExt.usrSubStatus>(cache, row, Values3, Labels3 );
}

protected void BAccount_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected del)
{
  if (del != null)
    del(cache, e);

  var row = (BAccount)e.Row;
  if (row == null) return;

  if (row.Status != "I")
    PXStringListAttribute.SetList<BAccountExt.usrSubStatus>(cache, row, Values2, Labels2);
  else
    PXStringListAttribute.SetList<BAccountExt.usrSubStatus>(cache, row, Values3, Labels3);
}
```